# Trying to run Facebook OAuth in R-Cloud for a Research App. I cannot figure out how to copy/paste Site URL into Settings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, metadata, facebook-oauth, facebook-requests

I have been trying to request data from Facebook for a research project, and I have been authorized for everything on the research side of the Meta API. I have all of the tokens and VPN credentials I need to access ad-targeting data and make the requests through an R-Script. The problem is that every time I try to run "fboath" with the "RFacebook" package, it gives me an error.

```
> fboauth <- fbOAuth(appid,appsecret)
Copy and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings: http://localhost:1410/ 
When done, press any key to continue...
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Error: Authentication failed.
```

All of the troubleshooting I have read on the internet says to add a "Product" to my App for a website. However, with research access, there is no "Product" link to add a URL. I tried adding "localhost" to the App Domains in Basic Settings, but it disappears every time I save it. When in R, I have copied and pasted the URL into my browser and also pressed "enter" to proceed and it gives me an error with no code every time (see below-- this is what my console says when I run the command).